# Facebook iframe application insert comment , like and share

Tags: facebook, iframe, comments, share

I'm creating my facebook APP with Html iframe.

I need , when the user arrive on the app in facebook site, the can comment, like and share the application.

Some times ago I do this with the `<fb:comments>` and something else, but now I've read that I must to use the Javascript SDK but I don't found clear informations.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the place for clear information on using the Comments, Like and Share/Invite

Comments: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Like: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Share app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/